# Display latest webcam image in thumbnail

Tags: php, webcam

I've been trying for days to display a thumbnail of my weather cam. The server path is as follows

public_html
..cam
...20121012
...20121013
...20121014

The date folder are auto created everyday by my webcam settings. So everyday it will create a new folder and name it date('Ymd').

I'm using the following script to have the image displayed on my wordpress sidebar, but I can't get it to work. Furthermore, I would like to have it displayed as a thumbnail and when a visitor clicks on it, to have it open slightly larger (real size) in a popup screen.

```
<?php
chdir('/home/deb57301n2/domains/meteowestkust.be/public_html/cam/');
$subdirname = date('Ymd').'/';
echo getcwd();
$newest_mtime = 0;
$show_file = 'webcam_offline.png';
if ($handle = opendir($subdirname)) {
 while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..')) {
       $mtime = filemtime($subdirname.$file);
       if ($mtime > $newest_mtime) {
          $newest_mtime = $mtime;
          $show_file = $subdirname.$file;
       }
    }
  }
}
print '<img src="' .$show_file. '" alt="Weather Cam - West Coast - Belgium">';
?>
```

any help is highly appreciated !

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get the correct `$show_file`? Creating thumbnails is answered multiple times already so ask a specific question about that if you are stuck.

Comment: It show you any error? or the image is just not displaying? Try putting the image file's name in the src manually to see if it works first.

about the thumbnail you can just create an image thumbnail on runtime and delete it after it's shown, or just generate with your webcam settings a yourimagefilename_thumbnail.jpg

Comment: what you get in var_dump($show_file) before print statement ?

Comment: var_dump gives me this

/home/deb57301n2/domains/meteowestkust.be/public_html/camstring(18) "webcam_offline.png" string(47) "20121014/Weather_Nieuwpoort2012101409290001.jpg" string(47) "20121014/Weather_Nieuwpoort2012101410490001.jpg" string(47) "20121014/Weather_Nieuwpoort2012101411090001.jpg" string(47) "20121014/Weather_Nieuwpoort2012101411140001.jpg" string(47) "20121014/Weather_Nieuwpoort2012101411190001.jpg"

Comment: Problem is it doesn't give me any errors.. It just doesn't show the correct image. I get a question mark in a white box and when I right click on it and open it in a new tab, the url is incorrect.

It shows me http://www.meteowestkust.be/20121014/Weather_Nieuwpoort2012101411490001.jpg

While it should be 
http://www.meteowestkust.be/cam/20121014/Weather_Nieuwpoort2012101411490001.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It worked by adding

$show_file = '**/cam/**'.$subdirname.$file;

thanks for the help anyway guys !

Comment: look at [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function, it will change your life